# Algolia search on multiple indexes IOS

Tags: ios, swift, algolia

I have two indexes, Profile and Company. In profile it consists of user details along with userId. I have reference of userId in company index. Can I search users on company index by full name with the help of userId reference?

Company 

 userId:0WhaoyZhSKb6aUp181MHadWoBMM2 

 objectID:-Kr7JI35Zh_jSkIJw87z0WhaoyZhSKb6aUp181MHadWoBMM2

Profile 

 objectID::0WhaoyZhSKb6aUp181MHadWoBMM2 

 userName:dhcjcj 

 fullname:kurt angle 

 accountType:3 

 category:1 

 dob:996689700 

 email:tester31@gmail.com 

 fname:Kurt 

 gender:1 

 lname:Angle

Comment: show example for your object structure

Comment: I have updated question. Please have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would suggest you is to perform two calls then:

1. First one with the `name` as a search query to your `Profile` index to retrieve its `userId`
2. Second one with the `userId` as as search query to your `Company` index to retrieve the company

However, keep it mind that Algolia is a search engine and hence, will not provide you all the features of an RDBMS such as a `JOIN` that you would need in your case.

If I misunderstood your issue, could you provide us more details and your application ID in an email addressed to support@algolia.com, so that it would be easier to discuss about your specific use-case.

Comment: Yeah i am looking like join operation, my question was if i can perform on single call. Thanks for your answer.